# Xamarin - iOS Async Task in an override function

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I would like to make a service call to a REST API to check a value and if true, take the user to a new page. Instead of presenting a view controller, I'd like to just use a segue that I have wired up.

The service call to check the value is async Task, and I am calling it when a segue tries to fire (when the user presses the button)

```cs
public override bool ShouldPerformSegue(string segueIdentifier, NSObject sender)
{
    .. run check here, and return true or false to fire the segue
}
```

The problem is that C# wants me to modify this method to be async Task or async void or async Task but that breaks the 'override' since i'm no longer overriding.

What is the correct approach to handle a call with async programming, and then once the call finishes, take the user away?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to start your method in a `Task` and when finished take the user away.

Example:

```
var someTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var EventModal = await Method();
    await Navigation.PushAsync(Page(EventModal.Stuff));
});
```

Comment: Problem with this is that your still performing something async which might go wrong with certain timing. Doing a service call in shouldperform segue should be avoided anyways.